# Odata connets but cant get the data

Tags: odata, sapui5

I'm trying to develop an sapui app that connets to tha sap and collect some data, here is my code, Extracted request part.

```
var sServiceUrl = "http://isttst5007.unilever.com:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSNAP_BEG_SRV";
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, true);

    var oJsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

    oModel.read("/DumpsetSet?", null, null, true, function (oData, repsonse) {
        oJsonModel.setData(oData);
    });
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oJsonModel)

    console.log(oJsonModel.getProperty("/d/results"));
```

It connects server and asks username, password. But however It can not collect data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the read is a asynchronous task could lead to the problem that when you do the console.log, the model isn't filled with the data yet. 
Could you try to do the console.log inside the success function of the read function?
If there is data displayed, the asynchronous task is causing the "problem".

```
var sServiceUrl = "../sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSNAP_BEG_SRV";
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, true);

var oJsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

oModel.read("/DumpsetSet?", null, null, true, function (oData, repsonse) {
    oJsonModel.setData(oData);
    // Here the JSON Model is filled with the right data
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oJsonModel)
    console.log(oJsonModel.getProperty("/d/results"));
});
```

Comment: İ tried to add a button and  in press i wrote the console.log but after waiting a while and press it didn't  work again. Could it be about my gateway service eventough I can acces with the request links?

Comment: And if you do the console.log in the read function of the model like i proposed? Still no data?

Comment: I tried that and could get the data but It can not initialize to jsonmodel. Do you know any different way to set dis data to json format?

Comment: When I print odata I can see whole datas but when I print jsonmodel just see undefined.

Comment: That's the problem of asynchronous tasks. If you don't understand why your JSON Model isn't defined the time you want to get it, then please read something about asynchronous Javascript. I added another answer where the JSON Model is filled

Comment: I figure it out and solved, it was about my code. just because of trying to bind wrong path. I also learned asynchronous tasks, big thanks to you.